# Who are the other Hogwarts ghosts?

Tags: harry-potter, hogwarts

In Hogwarts we learn about the 4 House ghosts. The Fat Friar, Nearly-Headless Nick, the Bloody Baron, and the Grey Lady. Also, we’re introduced to Moaning Myrtle, Professor Binns, and Peeves (if you could count him) but there are supposed to be at least 20 ghosts at Hogwarts.

> Then something happened which made him jump about a foot in the air – several people behind him screamed.
>
> ‘What the –?’
>
> He gasped. So did the people around him. About twenty ghosts had just streamed through the back wall. Pearly-white and slightly transparent, they glided across the room talking to each other and hardly glancing at the first-years.

<sup>*Harry Potter and the Sorcerer's Stone*, Chapter 7, "The Sorting Hat"</sup>

Who are the other ghosts mentioned here? Does anyone know? Could the Headless Hunt be there as well?

Comment: https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/hogwarts-ghosts

Comment: I want to say there is an article on Pottermore but I am not sure it names them all. Peeves is a poltergeist but the funny thing is geist is German for ghost. But Rowling sees them as having a distinction.

Comment: Ha. Looked away a moment and Valorum links it to you. Not at computer though so all the better.

Comment: Possible duplicate. This question already has an answer here. https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/166931/how-many-ghosts-haunt-hogwarts

Comment: @RichS - I'd say it isn't a dupe. OP is asking for ghosts *besides* the ones listed in that answer.

Comment: @Pryftan I don't think Rowling considers Peeves to not be a ghost. He's a ghost *who is more specifically a poltergeist*. Also, word meanings in German don't matter, as Rowling is writing in English.

Comment: @sgroves You clearly missed my point with German. And I'm pretty sure Rowling did say he wasn't a ghost. Now I'm a literal thinker so it's possible that your interpretation is valid; but it's also possible that my interpretation is valid: she doesn't consider him a ghost so isn't part of the list of ghosts. As for German I was only pointing it out out of interest (and iirc Pottermore has something about it though I could be wrong there).

Comment: @Pryftan I didn't miss your point. In English, "ghost" and "geist" have different meanings.

Comment: @sgroves I was speaking on the etymology level only. I couldn't care less that they have different meanings in English (your suggestion that it's irrelevant is what I suggested you missed my point for - because you did and entirely). It doesn't take anything away from my comment whatever you may believe. Fact is she makes a distinction between Peeves and ghosts. Whether you want to say she has it as a modifier or whatever else is irrelevant when she makes a distinction. And it still missed my point utterly.

Comment: @Pryftan Dude really? "Peeves is a poltergeist but the funny thing is geist is German for ghost. *But Rowling sees them as having a distinction.*" I was replying to the part I've italicized. Rowling sees those 2 words as having a distinction because they DO have a distinction *in English*, which is the language she's writing in. That's all I meant. You seemed surprised by this, so I figured I'd clear it up. My point is that the etymology is irrelevant.

Comment: @sgroves It isn't irrelevant to what I was trying to say. But if you want go ahead and carry on and believe otherwise; this is an exercise in futility as I already tried to reword it before. The funny thing though is I was talking about what **I find interesting wrt etymology in one specific context**. You clearly missed that though you tried very hard to tell me otherwise. Despite me saying that you did miss it. Because you did. Whatever. It matters not. I know she's writing in English; *that's very obvious* though there is such a thing as a translation (again irrelevant though).

Comment: @Pryftan You can be as snobby as you want, but you said Rowling sees the two words as having a distinction, as though this is a crazy thing to assume. But it's *not crazy in English*. The words have *different definitions in English*. Not sure how many more times I'll need to repeat this ... do you understand now?

Comment: @sgroves If that is 'snobby' to you then I pity you. Yes I said that. But I wasn't talking about just English; I did say etymologically speaking which I specifically mentioned *German*. I know they have different meanings in English but more correctly: poltergeist = ghost in English and also German (from poltern ‘create a disturbance’, Geist ‘ghost’); then you have poltergeist and ghost in English being the same (semantics aside). Geist doesn't count because she didn't call them 'geist'. This is beyond silly; I make a comment that I find something interesting and it turns into this? Done.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

## They weren’t named in the books - but JKR said she had more.

The only ghosts actually named in the books are the four House ghosts, Moaning Myrtle, Professor Binns and Peeves (though he’s a poltergeist, not actually a ghost, and not considered as one by the Hogwarts ghosts either). However, JKR did have names for a few other ghosts who were never mentioned in the books or movies.

> In the very earliest list of ghosts I ever wrote for Hogwarts, I included Myrtle (initially named ‘Wailing Wanda’), Professor Binns, the Grey Lady (then called ‘the Whispering Lady’) and the Bloody Baron. There was also a Black Knight, The Toad (which left ectoplasm all over its classroom), and a ghost I rather regret not using: his name was Edmund Grubb, and the notes beside his name say: ‘Expired in the doorway of the Dining Hall. Sometimes stops people getting in, out of spite. Fat Victorian ghost. (Ate poisonous berries).’ 
> <sub><sup>*[Hogwarts Ghosts (Pottermore)](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/hogwarts-ghosts)*</sup></sub>

In the books, though, none of those names are used - the other 14 (or 13 if counting Peeves the Poltergeist) are unnamed, similarly to how we don’t know the names of every student at Hogwarts, though we know there are more than the named ones.

## They seemed to be residents - they were arguing about Peeves.

The about-twenty ghosts who were talking amongst themselves were talking about Peeves, and what they should do about him. This doesn’t seem like something the Headless Hunt, or other visiting ghosts, would be discussing.

> “He gasped. So did the people around him. About twenty ghosts had just streamed through the back wall. Pearly-white and slightly transparent, they glided across the room talking to each other and hardly glancing at the first-years. They seemed to be arguing. What looked like a fat little monk was saying, ‘Forgive and forget, I say, we ought to give him a second chance –’
>
> ‘My dear Friar, haven’t we given Peeves all the chances he deserves? He gives us all a bad name and you know, he’s not really even a ghost – I say, what are you all doing here?” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone, Chapter 7 (The Sorting Hat)*</sup></sub>

Since the ghosts all seem to be arguing about Peeves, a problem unique to Hogwarts that visitors likely wouldn’t care enough to be arguing over, it seems likely that the ghosts involved in that conversation were residents of Hogwarts.

Comment: Ogliarchy at work:  the names of twenty ghosts becomes more important to readers than the names of many more living but otherwise unremarkable students.

Comment: Last I checked, Professor Bonn's was named in the books, yet you haven't included him.

Comment: @can-ned_food There have been questions about some of the unnamed students as well.

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing He’s already mentioned in the question as being named in the books, the OP knew about him already.

Comment: @Bellatrix - By that argument the OP already mentioned and knew about the other 5 1/2 ghosts as well.

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing Ah, you mean my list of the ones mentioned in the question! I could have sworn he was in there. Oh well, I’ll add him in!

Comment: And I just realised that I can't spell, so Hogwarts now has a new ghost teacher: Professor Bonn.

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing Well, there’s another named ghost then! ;) Thanks for pointing out my omission so I could add him in! :)

Answer (score 18):

### While they never appeared in the books, three more ghosts are mentioned in Rowling's drafts.

- **Black Knight**
- **The Toad** - "left ectoplasm all over its classroom"
- **Edmund Grubb** - "Expired in the doorway of the Dining Hall. Sometimes stops people getting in, out of spite. Fat Victorian ghost. (Ate poisonous berries)."

> In the very earliest list of ghosts I ever wrote for Hogwarts, I included Myrtle (initially named ‘Wailing Wanda’), Professor Binns, the Grey Lady (then called ‘the Whispering Lady’) and the Bloody Baron. There was also a **Black Knight**, **The Toad** (which left ectoplasm all over its classroom), and a ghost I rather regret not using: his name was **Edmund Grubb**, and the notes beside his name say: ‘Expired in the doorway of the Dining Hall. Sometimes stops people getting in, out of spite. Fat Victorian ghost. (Ate poisonous berries).’
>
> <sub>[Pottermore - Hogwarts Ghosts](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/hogwarts-ghosts)</sub>

> [image]
> <sub>CBS 60 Minutes - J.K. Rowling - September 1999</sub>